# PHP Ler TXT, apagar linhas, criar novo arquivo

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, foreach, txt

Quero usar PHP e o xamp/wamp para fazer a seguinte tarefa no meu computador sem a necessidade de upload/download:

Tenho dezenas de arquivos TXT no computador, cada TXT contendo apenas 1 nome por linha, sem traços, pontos, ;, etc.

Quero fazer uma busca, por exemplo, por todas as pessoas com sobrenome "Silva" nessas dezenas de arquivos, então o PHP iria ler todos os arquivos TXT, mover todos os nomes com "Silva" para silva.txt e salvar os 2 arquivos.

Até aqui me explicaram o seguinte:
A parada é pegar os arquivos e passar no php por um foreach em cada linha, add no banco de dados, mas antes de add fazer uma pesquisa se já existe o dado no arquivo novo, depois salvar os 2 arquivos.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como fazer isso?

Confesso que não entendo quase nada de PHP e estou batendo cabeça p/ fazer esse foreach em vários arquivos ao mesmo tempo, criar esse BD, criar um novo arquivo, mover tudo, ver se tem dado repetido, colocar em ordem alfabética e salvar todos os arquivos depois.

Tá complicado disso funcionar....

Comment: Poste o código do que você tentou até agora. E em que parte do código você tem dúvidas, assim fica mais fácil de esclarecer as dúvidas.

Comment: Se os arquivos estiverem em uma única pasta, é mais fácil... Estão??

Comment: Estão todos na mesma pasta. Encontre isso aqui para ler os arquivos. Processando todos os arquivos de um diretório

<?php
$dh = dir ("/home/1www/");
while ($entrada = $dh->read()) {
        print $entrada . "<br>";
}
$dh->close();
?>

Comment: Para abrir o arquivo para gravação encontrei isso: <?php
$fp = fopen("./dados.txt", "w");
while (!feof($fp)){
    $char .= fgetc($fp);
} 
fclose($fp);
echo $char."<br><br>";
?>

Comment: <?php 
 
$file = file("lista.txt"); 
 
foreach ($file as $i => $valor) { 
 
}  usort($files, "porData");

Comment: Estou tentando juntar todas essas partes e fazer funcionar.

Comment: Os arquivos são simples: 001.txt, 005.txt, eles tem apenas um nome por linha, depois ENTER, todos TXT e na mesma pasta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$base = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; // Diretório onde estão os arquivos txt.
$files = glob($base.'*.txt'); // Pega todos os arquivos que terminam com .txt

$search = 'silva'; // a palavra que deseja buscar
$found = array();
$arr = array();
// Itera os arquivos encontrados
foreach ($files as $file) {

    // Lê cada arquivo em um array
    $arr = file($file);
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        // Se encontrar a palavra, guarda no array $found e remove do array que leu o arquivo.
        if (stripos($v, $search) !== false) {
            $found[] = trim($arr[$k]);
            unset($arr[$k]);
        }
    }
    // Salva os dados no arquivo, com os nomes removidos
    if (!empty($found)) {
        file_put_contents($file, implode('', $arr));
    }

}
// salva todos os nomes encontrados
if (!empty($found)) {
    file_put_contents($base.'silva.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $found));
}

unset($found, $arr);
```

Comment: Oi Daniel, instalei o Xampp novamente e funcionou tudo legal.

Comment: Agradeço muito pela sua ajuda, vou ter horas de trabalho pra fazer aqui mas seriam meses se vc não tivesse ajudado.